# Characters on $PGL(2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-groups, characters

I am interested in computations with characters on $PGL(2, F)$ and not in $GL(2, F)$, and have some issues concerning definitions.

The notion of conductor is standard for characters $\chi$ of a $p$-adic number field $F=F_p$, and is defined as the least $r$ such that $\chi$ is trivial on $1+p^r\mathcal{O}_p$. Since characters of $GL(2, F)$ are $\chi \circ \det$ for characters $\chi$ on $F$, it is enough to define conductors for characters.

I am wondering about the analogous definitions for $PGL(2, F)$. Characters on $PGL(2, F)$ can be seen as characters on $GL(2, F)$ trivial on the center. Do we know their form, as $\chi \circ \det$ for specific kind of $\chi$ (trivial on squares?). What is the relation between the conductor of $\chi \circ \det$ and the one of $\chi$ in this setting? Is there a group such that $F^2(1+p^r\mathcal{O}_p)$ such that a character trivial on it is a character of $PGL(2)$ of conductor less than $r$?

Comment: I'm curious about the notation $PGL(é)$: what does it mean?

Comment: @Qfwfq That I made a typo, now corrected :)

Comment: Ah okay, I suspected that, but.. who knows! :)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292424/meaning-of-a-highly-ramified-character-for-reductive-groups

Comment: I think also "a group such that $F^2(1 + p^r\mathscr O_p)$" is meant to be "a group such *as* $(F^\times)^2(1 + p^r\mathscr O_p)$".

Comment: Since $\mathrm{SL}(2, F)$ is generated by its unipotents, any character of $\mathrm{PGL}(2, F)$ is trivial on the image of $\mathrm{SL}(2, F)$.  Since $\mathrm{PGL}(2, F)/\mathrm{SL}(2, F)$ is isomorphic to $F^\times/(F^\times)^2$ *via* the determinant, indeed the characters of $\mathrm{PGL}(2, F)$ are as you describe.

Comment: It is not quite clear what "the conductor of $\chi \circ \det$" should mean *a priori* (hence how to compare it to the conductor of $\chi$), since $\mathrm{PGL}(2, F)$ carries multiple natural filtrations, unlike $F^\times = \mathrm{GL}(1, F)$ which carries only a single natural filtration.  One possible definition would be just to *define* the conductor of $\chi \circ \det$ to be that of $\chi$.

Comment: In general one replaces the notion of conductor by the notion of depth (for which see the papers of Moy and Prasad), and the depth of $\chi \circ \det$ is $r - 1$ in the situation you describe.  (I am assuming that $p \ne 2$.)